# What characterizes the matrices with the following properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An $n$-by-$m$ matrix $A$ is called "good" if for any real number $x$, there exists an $n$-by-$1$ vector $\mathbf{p}$ such that:

$$A\cdot \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{0}_m$$
$$p_1 = x$$

An example of a "good" matrix is:

```
1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1
```

Since for every $x$ the vector $\mathbf{p} = (x, -x, -x/2, -x/2)^T$ satisfies both requirements.

An example of a "not good" matrix is:

```
1 1
1 2
```

Since for e.g. $x=3$, $p_2$ must be $-3$ to have a 0 at the first row but $-6$ to have a 0 at the second row.

Is there a known term, or a simple characterization, to "good" matrices?

Comment: The first column of $A$ is a linear combination of the other columns.

Comment: for $A=[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m]$ your property is $a_1 \in span(a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_m)$.

Comment: A more traditional presentation of the answer from the other comments: $A$ is "good" if and only if 
$$
\operatorname{rank}[a_1 \ \ a_2 \ \ \cdots \ \ a_m] = \operatorname{rank}[a_2 \ \ \cdots \ \ a_m].
$$